# ActionbarSherlock: Set logo width / height

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

is there a way (theme/style xml) to specify the actionbar logo width / height.

Im using ActionbarSherlock and Im playing around with an transparent Actionbar, where I want to display the app logo a little bit bigger than the default width  and height.

Or alternatively: is there a way to reduce the top and bottom space (padding) of the action bar. Im shore there is a simple theme style attribute that I have to set, but I could not find the name of this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in `ActionBarSherlock`'s source code I see this attribute :

```
<!-- Specifies a layout to use for the "home" section of the action bar. -->
<attr name="homeLayout" format="reference" />
```

I've never tested this, but I would give a try.Hope this helps you to solve your problem. : )